# how to multiple database in vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, vb.net

Is it possible to connect multiple databases to a program

```
----------------------------
Using con As New Odbc.OdbcConnection
        con.ConnectionString =
                "Driver={Mysql odbc 3.51 Driver};Server=192.168.0.155;" &
                "DataBase=DB1;uid=root;pwd=gnsa;port=3306"
               con.Open()
        Using cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText =
            "INSERT INTO [;DataBase=DB2;uid=root;pwd=gnsa;port=3306].[transfer_file] SELECT * FROM [DB1].[sta_trn_tfoliotran]"

            Dim rdr As Odbc.OdbcDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            Do While rdr.Read
                Console.WriteLine(rdr("DB1_Text") & " | " & rdr("DB2_Text"))
            Loop
        End Using
        con.Close()
    End Using
----------------------------
```

I was to fetch the datas in Database1 and want to insert in database2.

Comment: Of course it's possible. Can you retrieve data from a database without inserting any? Of course you can.  Can you insert data into a database without retrieving any.  Of course you can.  You probably already know how to do both those things so you already know how to do what you're asking.

Comment: From your CommandText you clearly have no idea how SQL query works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is possible, I think you already know what to do. I'll just give a little advice for you. so that your codes don't mess up.

```
Private Sub Button(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
    'call the sub methods'
    retrieve_data() 
    insert_data()
End Sub

Private Sub retrieve_data()
    'Set your first database here'
    con.ConnectionString =
            "Driver={Mysql odbc 3.51 Driver};Server=192.168.0.155;" &
            "DataBase=DB1;uid=root;pwd=gnsa;port=3306"
    'Retrieve the data here'
End Sub

Private Sub insert_data()
    'Set the second database'
    con.ConnectionString =
            "Driver={Mysql odbc 3.51 Driver};Server=192.168.0.155;" &
            "DataBase=DB2;uid=root;pwd=gnsa;port=3306"
    'Insert your data here'
End Sub
```